# how to save the value of the new list

Tags: c#, console

class student_details
    {
        public int studId { get; set; }

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UGender { get; set; }

    public int UAge { get; set; }

}
```

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string studYear = "";
        int Id = 0;
        //InputDetails
        #region
        Input:

        Console.WriteLine("\nStudent Year Identifier\n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter FirstName: ");
        string Fname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter LastName: ");
        string Lname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Gender: ");
        string Gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Age: ");
        int Age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Age < 14)
        {
            studYear = "N/A";
        }
        else if (Age <= 15)
        {
            studYear = "FirstYear";
        }
        else if (Age <= 17)
        {
            studYear = "SecondYear";
        }
        else if (Age <= 19)
        {
            studYear = "ThirdYear";
        }
        else if (Age >= 20)
        {
            studYear = "ForthYear";
        }
        #endregion


        //List
        #region

        List<Model.student_details> listOfstudentDetails = new List<Model.student_details>();
        #endregion
        //Looping
        #region
        Console.WriteLine("Add more student details (Yes or No)?");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer == "Yes" || answer == "YES" || answer == "yes" || answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
        {
            Console.Clear();

            listOfstudentDetails.Add(new Model.student_details { studId = Id++, FirstName = Fname, LastName = Lname, UGender = Gender, Uage = Age });
            goto Input;
        }
        else if (answer == "No" || answer == "NO" || answer == "no" || answer == "n" || answer == "N")
        {
            Console.Clear();

            listOfstudentDetails.Add(new Model.student_details { studId = Id++, FirstName = Fname, LastName = Lname, UGender = Gender, Uage = Age });
            //var filterName = listOfstudentDetails;
            foreach (var item in listOfstudentDetails)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student Id = " + item.studId + ": Firstname is " + item.FirstName + " Lastname is " + item.LastName + " and Gender is " + item.UGender+ " and Age is equal to " + item.Uage + " and his age is applicable for " + studYear);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        #endregion

    }
```

// Upon running the application, the program will ask to enter the student details. There's no limit in entering student details. After the creation of the details, the program will always ask the user if it will "Add more student details (Yes or No)?" If the user enter the "Yes" the program will ask to enter following questions again. If "No" the program will execute the list of the students with the note in the end of the string like the given example below.

Output:
List of student details:

Student Id = 1: His firstname is johnny and his lastname is bravo. Age is equal to 20 and his age is applicable for Third Year.

Student Id = 2: His firstname is Smith and his lastname is Barak Age is equal to 19 and his age is applicable for Third Year.

Student Id = 3: Her firstname is Jenny and her lastname is Swift. Age is equal to 14 and her age is applicable for First Year

Comment: why have you tagged this question with "basic"?

Comment: What are you trying to achive exactly? What is the problem?

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with your code? The only thing I can see is that studYear is only set during input. So when you output the list it will only show the correct value for the last student...

Comment: they said its basic coding sir. sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: The problem sir is  i want to save new list here List<Model.student_details> listOfstudentDetails = new List<Model.student_details>();
but only 1 list will show i want to show all list that i input in every time i loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the list with a new list every time you loop.

Try defining your list above the `Input` label.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite your list after every input cycle. That way you only ever have one Student in your list.

Move your declaration and list initialization to the top of the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string studYear = "";
    int Id = 0;
    List<Model.student_details> listOfstudentDetails = new List<Model.student_details>();
}
```

It's generally a good practice to declare and initialize your variables at the beginning of their scope.

Also you shouldn't use `goto`  to repeat your input cycle. You should employ a `while` or `do-while` loop.

```
//initialize your variables
...

do
{
    //input students
    ...
} while (answerWasYes);

//list students
...
```

Your goto structures was a main contributor to that problem because it makes program flow harder to follow.

Comment: sir it will show the last list that i input. 1 line only.

Comment: The line where you write `new List<Model.student_details>()` has to be before your loop/goto label